# Vector bundles on affine scheme

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

I have already asked similar questions before, but now I realized that there a nice
general way to ask what I want. Namely let $X$ be a normal affine variety over
a field $k$. Assume first that $k$ is finite. Then is it true that

1) IF $X$ is smooth, then the set of isomorphism classes of vector bundles of given rank on $X$ is finite?

2) More generally, is it true that for any $X$ the set of isomorphism classes of Cohen-Macaulay torsion free sheaves of fixed generic rank is finite?

When the field $k$ is arbitrary then I would expect that there exists a finite-dimensional
(over $k$) family of vector bundles or Cohen-Macaulay sheaves which contains
every isomorphism class. Is this true?

Answer (score 10):

Suppose that $X = \mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1 \setminus \Delta$, where $\Delta$ is the diagonal. The Picard group of $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ is $\mathbb{Z}^2$. Yanking out $\Delta$ should just kill the generator $(1,1)$ in $\mathbb{Z}^2$, so $\mathrm{Pic}(X)$ should be $\mathbb{Z}$. So there is an infinite discrete parameter describing line bundles on $X$. Unless I am missing something...

Comment: Thanks, I have somehow missed that kind of example. I wonder whether
requiring that all  the Chern classes of the vector bundle in question are equal to 0 will change anything...

Answer (score 5):

As shown by David, the answer is **no** for line bundles.

More generally, the answer in **no** even for higher dimensional vector bundles. In fact, in his paper "[Vector bundle over affine surfaces birationally equivalent to ruled surfaces](http://www.jstor.org/pss/1970667)" Murthy proves the following results:

**(1)** Let $V$ be an irreducible affine non-singular surface defined over an algebraically closed field $k$ and such that $V$ is birational to $C \times \mathbb{P}^1$, vhere $C$ is a curve. Then any vector bundle over $V$ is a direct sum of a trivial bundle and a line bundle. In general, there are infinitely many equivalence classes of line bundles (as shown by David  for $V= \mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1 \setminus \Delta$).

**(2)** There exist an affine, nonsingular rational variety of dimension $3$ over which there are infinitely many non-isomorphic *indecomposable* vector bundles of rank $>1$.

Comment: If you already have infinite number of line bundles you can twist any given bundle of higher rank to produce infinite number of vector bundles of that rank, can't you?

Comment: Of course you can. The point of $(2)$ is that in dimension $3$ you find *indecomposable* vector bundles of any rank, in contrast with the case of affine ruled surfaces, where every vector bundle splits as a sum of line bundles.

Comment: Keeping in mind, of course, that you cannot twist beyond the top rank = dimension of your variety, since any vector bundle whose rank exceeds the dimension necessarily splits a trivial line bundle.